# What is the media type of an OpenAPI schema?

Tags: swagger, openapi, media-type

Whenever searching for this I find resources on how to specify the media type of a resource that the schema defines, but I can't see an answer on what the actual media type of the schema itself is.

Given the way HTTP works, it makes sense to me that if I request the right content type with the Accept header, my server can respond appropriately.

Thus, if I request `/products` with `Accept: application/json` I would get products in JSON format, but if I requested `openapi-whatever` I would get the OpenAPI schema.

I *think* I can probably use either `application/openapi+json` or `application/openapi+yaml`, but I can't see anything about it in the actual [specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification).

I'm not sure whether or not I actually want to use the Accept header for this difference, but I certainly want to respond with the correct Content-Type header in any case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OpenAPI Initiative's Technical Steering Committee (TSC) [approved](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/110#issuecomment-364498200) the following media types:

```
application/vnd.oai.openapi      (YAML variant)
application/vnd.oai.openapi+json (JSON only variant)
```

with an optional `version` parameter:

```
application/vnd.oai.openapi;version=2.0
```

However, these media types are not yet registered with [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Comment: Thanks, I will use this until something changes!

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be newer (Sept. 2021):

- application/openapi+yaml
- application/openapi+json

https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-polli-rest-api-mediatypes-00.html